# what is the difference between .h and .H head file in C++?

Tags: c++

what is the difference between .h and .H head file in C++? when I use OpenFOAM which is a Computational Fluid Dynamics open source software developed by C++, I find it's head file name are .H rather than tranditional form .h, Why?

Comment: Using a case insensitive filing system - windows perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

For C++, there is no difference at all.
Apparently, the authors of OpenFOAM just liked .H more than .h

Still, there is something to pay attention to: If you're programming for Unix-like systems (Linux...), file names are case sensitive, so with the wrong name, the file won't be found (=> compiler error).

Comment: 4 downvotes for the question in, what, 10sec? ... Hm.

Comment: seems like a reasonable question to me, I guess some people are in a bad mood

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day it doesn't matter for compilers of Windows environment. If you are in an environment where the file name are case sensitive like Ubuntu or other Linux based system then it really matters because of case sensitivity of the file system.

But most often you use the compiler supplied header files and some times you can make your own header files, in the latter case whatever name you give to your header file you have to reference the same in your program and if you are working in Linux environment then you have to be aware of the case sensitivity otherwise in Windows you just give the name of your header file with proper extension where you are referencing it.